# How do I fix my regex ^\d+[-\d]?\d* to match 123-45 but not 123-?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression to match an ID in the following format

`123`
or
`123-45`

There can by *any amount of numbers* before an after the hyphen. The problem right now is that my expression matches `123-` and I need it not too (hyphen is optional, but if it's present then there MUST be at least one digit after it).

I have tried
`^\d+[-\d+]?`
and `^\d+[-\d]?\d*`, but neither work.

Comment: @Dunnie - These are hardly "unnecessary tags" - In fact, we always ask people to *add* these tags! It is relevant to the question if the regex is using the .Net engine, or is used in Asp.Net for validation.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

You want to have `-` optional with at least a single digit. `[-\d]` allows a hyphen *or* a digit, followed by zero digits. A similar pattern in `^\d+(?:-\d)?\d*$`.

See also:

- [Capturing and non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - `(...)` and `(?:...)` - Allows grouping of quantifiers, like `?`.
- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - `[...]` - Allows selecting a single character out of a set.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
\d+(?:-\d+)?
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kobi said - you almost had it right, you just mixed up the square with the round brackets

Answer (score 0):

How about: \d+-?

Matching all digits and optionally a hyphen

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 ^\d+[-\d]?\d+
```

Replacing the `*` with a `+` forces it to match one or more of the preceding element, rather than zero or more.